# El campo de texto solo muestra la primera palabra que contiene la variable

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo un crud en php y ahora estoy haciendo la opción de editar, cuando le doy al botón editar me lleva a otro formulario donde en los campos de texto deben aparecer los datos de los productos. El problema es que si alguno de los datos, como la descripción. Tiene más de una palabra, solo se muestra la primera. Pero luego imprimo la variable con un echo y me muestra la frase completa. Este es el código que me da problemas.

```
<body>

    <?php
        echo $_POST["descripcion"]; // Muestra la descripción completa
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <form action="editar.php" method="post">
                    <label for="nom">Nombre</label> <br />
                    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="nom" id="nombre" value=<?= "$_POST[nombre]" ?>> <br /><br />

                    <label for="desc">descripción</label> <br />
                    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="desc" id="descripcion" value=<?= "$_POST[descripcion]" ?>> <br /><br /> // Solo muestra la primera palabra

                    <label for="prec">precio</label> <br />
                    <input class="col-12" type="text" required name="prec" id="precio" value=<?= "$_POST[precio]" ?>> <br /><br />

                    <input class="btn btn-primary col-12" type="submit" value="enviar">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Y este es el resultado que me da.

[image: El campo de texto solo muestra la primera palabra]

Comment: El entrecomillado doble de los `value`'s debería ser así: `value="<?=$_POST['clave'];?>"`

Comment: Sí, era eso muchas gracias. Soy nuevo y no sabía cómo iba. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema estaba en el entrecomillado doble de los value. Lo tenía así

```
value=<?= "$_POST[descripcion]" ?>
```

Cuando debía ser así

```
value="<?=$_POST['clave'];?>"
```

Este cambio ha solucionado el problema